# gcc optimizations: how to deal with macro expantion in strncmp & other functions

Tags: gcc, macros, compiler-optimization, c-preprocessor

Take this sample code:

```
#include <string.h>
#define STRcommaLEN(str) (str), (sizeof(str)-1)

int main() {
    const char * b = "string2";
    const char * c = "string3";
    strncmp(b, STRcommaLEN(c));
}
```

If you don't use optimizations in GCC, all is fine, but if you add -O1 and above, as in `gcc -E -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -c -I/usr/local/include -O1 sample.c`, `strncmp` becomes a macro, and in preprocessing stage STRcommaLen is not expanded. In fact in resulting "code" `strncmp`'s arguments are completely stripped.

I know if I add `#define NEWstrncmp(a, b) strncmp (a, b)` and use it instead, the problem goes away. However, mapping your own functions to every standard function that may become a macro doesn't seem like a great solution.

I tried finding the specific optimization that is responsible for it and failed. In fact if I replace -O1 with all the flags that it enables according to `man gcc`, the problem goes away. My conclusion is that -O1 adds some optimizations that are not controlled by flags and this is one of them.

How would you deal with this issue in a generic way? There may be some macro magic I am not familiar with or compiler flags I haven't looked at? We have many macros and a substantial code base - this code is just written to demonstrate one example.

Btw, GCC version/platform is `gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)`.

Thanks,
Alen

Comment: If optimization breaks a valid program, that's a compiler bug that should be reported.

Comment: Nothing to do with gcc, it is glibc that choses to make strncmp a macro.

Comment: And it is perfectly legal for glibc to do that, see C99 7.1.4, first paragraph. "Any function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a function-like macro"

Comment: Try `(strncmp)(b, STRcommaLEN(c));`.

Comment: Thanks for comments, @Bamar - I was about to report it as a bug when I found out it's not a bug and they won't do anything about it.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I like your parentheses suggestion and it effectively solves the problem, however it gets rid of string-related optimizations completely. If you try `gcc -E -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -c -I/usr/local/include -O1 sample.c|less` and scroll to the bottom, you'll see strncmp and arguments untouched. Mapping your function to strncmp will still produce optimized output. I wonder if there is a way to modify my initial macro to have everything happen properly.

Comment: `STRcommaLEN(c)` isn't going to work anyway; `sizeof(c)` gives you the size in bytes of a pointer, not the length (or length+1) of the string.

Comment: You are right, example hastily written. `c` should have been a `#define` as well.

Comment: `strncmp(b, c, strlen(c));` isn't longer to write, and gcc knows how to optimize strlen (in this case it will even evaluate strncmp at compile-time...). Or you could use `strcmp`.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly noted that

> in preprocessing stage STRcommaLen is not expanded

- more precisely, not before the `strncmp` macro gets expanded. This inevitably leads to an error you probably overlooked or forgot to mention:

```
sample.c:7:30: error: macro "strncmp" requires 3 arguments, but only 2 given
```

Your conclusion

> that -O1 adds some optimizations that are not controlled by flags and
>   this is one of them

is also right - this is controlled by the macro `__OPTIMIZE__` which apparently gets set by `-O1`.

If I'd do something like that (which I probably wouldn't, in respect of the pitfall you demonstrated by using `sizeof` a `char *`), I'd still choose

> mapping your own functions to every standard function that may become
>   a macro

- but rather like

```
#include <string.h>
#define STRNCMP(s1, s2) strncmp(s1, s2, sizeof(s2)-1)

int main()
{
    const char b[] = "string2";
    const char c[] = "string3";
    STRNCMP(b, c);
}
```